# MYSQL: varchar json field, find key with value

Tags: mysql, json

So inside my table, I have a column named "data" that is varchar(3000).

This is basically a json blob, and this is example of what it holds:

```
{"homeWidgetToShow":"chat_and_notes","official":false,"nationalFederation":false,"categories":[],"activities":{"0":2,"2":7,"1":3},"clubsBlackList":[],"privateMembers":false,"alwaysShowDescription":false,"restrictMembersFromPositingForums":false}
```

Now I need to make a query that basically finds if inside `data.activities` there is a key that has value 3.

In this keys, we see there is a key "1" that has the value 3, so it should be matched.

Caveat is, activities key sometimes may not be set, also it is not always on the key with value "1".

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Hey Nick, I am using Mysql8

Comment: Have you tried JSON_EXTRACT or JSON_CONTAINS - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: Tried with few of json functions but was unsuccessful in what I wanted to achieve, so came here for an example solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT json, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json,"$.activities.1")) AS desiredValue FROM `table_name`;
```

**Note** - If `activities` is not set in JSON, it will return NULL.

`JSON_UNQUOTE` is used to remove the double quotes around the extracted values.

`JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.activities.*')` is used to extract all values within the activities object, regardless of their keys.

```
[2, 7, 3]
```

`JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.activities.1')` is used to extract value at index 1 within the activities object.

```
3
```

If you want to achieve using the Doctrine's QueryBuilder

```
$qb->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
        "JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(tableName.data, '$.activities.1'))",
        "3"
))

$qb->where($queryBuilder->expr()->like(
       "tableName.data", // partial search
        $queryBuilder->expr()->literal("%\"$1\":\"$3\"%")
))
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok, I have removed Thanks! - @GeorgRichter

Comment: Note OP says: also it is not always on the key with value "1"

Comment: I am inclined towards your solution - @Nick

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`MEMBER OF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) JSON operator in MySQL 8 to determine if `3` is one of the values in the `activities` element of the JSON:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE 3 MEMBER OF(data->>'$.activities.*')
```

Note if `activities` is not present, `JSON_EXTRACT` will return `NULL` and so will `MEMBER OF` in that case.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9pqUFkda)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(
  JSON_EXTRACT('{"activities":{"0":2,"2":7,"1":3}}', '$.activities.*'),
  '2','$');
```

Replace `'{"activities":{"0":2,"2":7,"1":3}}'` with target string or column, `'2'` with search keyword. This will return null when `$.activities` is not present. Will return 1 when 2 is found in the desired path, 0 when 2 is not found.

[JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)`(doc:json, path:char*)` extracts elements specified in `path` from `doc`, you can use wildcard `*` to match any key. After applying extract, it returns text `[2,3,7]` (seems like ordered), you can then use it as a json array.

[JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)`(doc:json, val:any[, path:varchar])` returns 1 when `candidate` is found in any `path`s inside `target`, returns 0 when non is found, or null when any argument is null.